# Relative View overlay in web - React Native

Tags: react-native, css-position, absolute, nativewind

I recently crafted a Dropdown component in React Native. However, I faced a challenge where the Flatlist content ended up positioned beneath the subsequent Dropdown component. This positioning issue prompted me to review my code. Here's the code snippet for reference:

**Dropdown Component:**

```
export const DropDown = ({
  className,
  setSelectedValue,
  label,
  defaultValue,
  padding,
  options,
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({});
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const labelTranslateY = new Animated.Value(
    value?.label || defaultValue ? -7 : 11
  );

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setShow((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handlePress = (item) => {
    setValue(item);
    setSelectedValue(item);
    setShow((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item)}>
      <View
        style={{}}
        className=" hover:bg-black cursor-pointer border-b border-gray-600/25 w-full flex flex-wrap flex-row "
      >
        <Text className="flex-1 py-1 px-2 text-left text-base  ">
          {item?.label || ""}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return (
    <View
      className={`w-full h-full z-10 border-2 border-[#A7A7A7] ${
        value?.label || defaultValue ? `bg-white` : `bg-[#E8E8E8]`
      }  rounded-md flex flex-row justify-between items-center p y-1 px-2 ${className}`}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity className="w-full z-10" onPress={handleToggle}>
        <View className="w-full flex z-10 flex-row justify-between items-center">
          <Text className="text-xs z-10">{value?.label || defaultValue}</Text>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={show ? faCaretUp : faCaretDown}
            style={{ width: "1.5rem", height: "1.5rem", color: "#A7A7A7" }}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Animated.Text
        style={[
          styles.label,
          {
            transform: [{ translateY: labelTranslateY }],
            backgroundColor:
              value?.label || defaultValue ? "white" : "transparent",
          },
        ]}
      >
        {label}
      </Animated.Text>

      {show ? (
        <View
          className={
            `${Platform.OS ==="web" ? "w-full" : "w-[106%]"} z-10 rounded-md overflow-hidden absolute  right-0 top-[100%]`
          }
        >
          <FlatList
            data={options}
            className=" w-full border z-10 border-gray-300 rounded-sm  bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl "
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.value}
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View></View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

**index.js**

```
const OverlapExample = () => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});

  const options = [
    { label: "jjjjj", value: "1" },
    { label: "kkkkk", value: "2" },
    { label: "lllll", value: "3" },
  ];

  const structData = [
    {
      options: options,
      value: 55,
      class: "h-12 p-1 w-1/4",
      name: "counter",
      label: "Counter",
    },
    {
      options: options,
      value: 55,
      class: "h-12 p-1 w-1/4",
      name: "category",
      label: "Category",
    },
    {
      options: options,
      value: 55,
      class: "h-12 p-1 w-1/4",
      name: "collection",
      label: "Collection",
    },
  ];

  const handleChange = (e, name) => {
    setFilters((prev) => {
      const newObject = { ...prev };
      newObject[`${name}`] = e;

      return newObject;
    });
  };

  return (
    <View className="w-full">
      {structData?.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <View key={index} className={`${item.class}`}>
            <DropDown
              setSelectedValue={(e) => handleChange(e, item.name)}
              options={item.options}
              label={item.label}
              className={`border-2 border-[#A7A7A7] rounded-md py-1 px-2`}
              defaultValue={item.label || ""}
            />
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

I'm currently exploring ways to address this problem and ensure that the Flatlist content properly aligns with the Dropdown component as intended in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add greater `zIndex` property to top level `dropdown` and decrease it to lower level dropdown.

**Example**

```
counter dropdown have : zIndex: 10000

category dropdown have : zIndex: 1000

collection dropdown have : zIndex: 100
```

hope it will help.